# Can't run my React Native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, build

for some reason I can't run my project with `npm run ios`. I receive a `Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist` error.
The funny part is that I can build, and run my project with xcode (debug).
Anyone got any idea why `npm run ios` throw an error, BUT xcode run smoothly?

Comment: Delete the files from ios/build. And then rebuild the project 'react-native run-ios'.

Comment: I do not have a build folder as I tried to delete it once, but after that as I wan't able to build it with npm run ios there isn't a build folder